# PySpark Pivoting a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So basically I have an input data frame as below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfcjV.png]

which I want to transform into below output

[image]

Can anyone please help me as to ho we can implement this using PySpark Dataframes ?

I tried different ways but could not find an optimal way to do the same

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0):

Do a groupby on common columns and collect the column with distinct values into a list.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

ans_df =  df.groupBy(F.col('HCP ID'), F.col('TERR ID')).agg(collect_list(F.col('PRODUCT')).alias("LINEUP"))
```